# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver" not found

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

Zend Framework Version: 1.21.2

I'm updating my app and in particular a package `doctrine/mongodb-odm`. I run into the above error.

my `.yml` files are defined like thus:

```
/configs/doctrinemappings/
- myFile.dcm.yml
- myFile1.dcm.yml
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
<?
 $driver = new \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(array(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/doctrinemappings/'));
 $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
?>
```

I have

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^2.4.2", <-- updated from 1.2.5
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^4.4"
    },
```

at my disposal. As the error says, `YamlDriver` not found. I have

`AnnotationDriver`, `SimplifiedXMLDriver`, `XMLDriver` & `AttributeDriver` at my disposal with my updated package. Can you give me some advice
or a pointer on how best to switch from yaml to one of the above?

It's my understanding, I'd have to use annotations on all my zf1 models to use docblocks for example instead of my current `.yml` files/setup.
(Assuming i chose `AnnotationDriver` option above). I've picked this as an example only and would be open to any of the other options.

Comment: Yaml support has been dropped in 2.x https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1734

I'd go with annotations: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.3/reference/annotations-reference.html

Comment: Is there any way of automating this as opposed to hand-editing all the models manually? I.e. at the cli for example `zf`

Comment: There was something like `doctrine:mapping:convert`,  I wonder if it works with odm